# Use gsap node module with Meteor

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor, npm, gsap

I'm trying to use the 'gsap' node module, explicitly the tool 'Draggable' of that package together with Meteor (a plain Meteor React app).

The installation via `meteor npm install gsap` works as expected.
However if i want to use the module in my code as suggested in the docs, the client crashes with multiple consecutive errors; the first is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier modules.js:132661

The suggested way to import gsap tools is shown [here](https://greensock.com/docs/NPMUsage). The error appears when i try to import a sub-module like so:

```
import Draggable from 'gsap/Draggable';
```

I don't quite understand the problem here. With other modules a simple `npm install` and `import x from y` just works. With gsap modules that does not seem to be the case.
I'd be grateful for any advice.

**Update:**

It seems the import of 'gsap' node module is now working!
Thanks for your answers!

I had some issues with Draggable import, as gsap wasn't defined inside of its constructor (*"_toArray is not a function"*). To make it work you have to register the plugin to gsap (added lines in main.jsx):

```
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { Draggable } from 'gsap/Draggable';

gsap.registerPlugin(Draggable);.
```

Comment: Hi, instead of doing "window.gsap = gsap" I think you could just do gsap.registerPlugin(Draggable);. Anyway thank you for the hint I was stuck with that as well.

Comment: Hi, thank you for posting this!
I edited my fix above, as your way of doing it is way better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gsap package contains ES6 code. ES6 in the node_modules folder [is not compiled by Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor-feature-requests/issues/6#issuecomment-341584527). Usually when publishing to npm, packages are transpiled into ES5. The editor of `gsap` should do it.

Two options for you to make this work inside Meteor:

• Option 1: clone the [source from github](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS) directly somewhere in your Meteor app, like /imports/lib/gsap. Then import as following `import Draggable from '/impots/lib/gsap/Draggable';`

• Option 2: clone the [source from github](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS) directly somewhere **outside** your Meteor app and use `npm install /path/to/the/cloned/folder` inside your meteor app ([see here for reference](https://github.com/meteor/meteor-feature-requests/issues/6#issuecomment-376638308)). Option 2 seems less robust to me when working as a team in the same project or when you will need to deploy your app

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now, option 1 seems to be fitting for me! The gsap npm module is not really intuitive it seems.

Comment: @NickG It should be simplified some in the next version of GSAP! We're working on it now.

Comment: @ZachSaucier thanks a lot! I'm looking forward to it.